# Error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Approval[] | (() => Approval[])'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am learning Typescript, wanted to ask about the meaning of the following error when initializing the state:

```
[approvals, setApprovals] = useState<Array<Approval>>({});
```

Where the Approval object is defined as follows:

```
import { IFile } from "./IFile";

export interface Approval {
  approvalDate: string,
  fileObj?: IFile
}
```

During state initialization I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Approval[] | (() => Approval[])'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type '() => Approval[]'.
    Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(): Approval[]'.ts(2345)
```

Do you what is the issue here?

Thank you

Comment: I don't use react, but the `Array<Approval>`  in `useState<Array<Approval>>` and `is not assignable to parameter of type 'Approval[] |` indicate, that `useState<Array<Approval>>` expects an array (of `Approval`)  as argument. But you are passing an empty object (`{}`) to it.

Comment: Quite simply, `{}` is not an array. Although even if you made it `[{}]` (and I have no idea if you need to change the value or the types, not having any idea what your component does or what `Approval` represents), this wouldn't work as the `approvalDate` property is required in your interface.

Comment: perhaps you mean to initialise the state as an empty array, so `[]` rather than `{}`? But as I said, it's all guesswork without knowing what your component is intended for.

Comment: To add a bit of advice to @t.niese's great dissection of the central issue, just change `{}` to `[]`,

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[approvals, setApprovals] = useState<Approval[]>([]);
```

Note:

```
Approval[]
```

is same type as

```
Array<Approval>
```